# Numerically integrating an interpolation function and its derivative

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation-function

I am working with a differential equation I cannot solve analytically. I solved it numerically. I have data representing position versus time in a list. I have working code that generates an interpolation function for the data, and a function that defines the interpolation function's derivative. Both of these quantities enter my differential equation. When I numerically integrate, the final result comes out much smaller than what I expect (about 2 or 3 orders of magnitude). I oberved that the derivative of the interpolation function has wild swings into regions where no actual data points exist.

Is it possible to get rid of these swings and smooth out the derivative of the interpolation function? Or, perhaps the problem could be solved in a completely different way that I did not think of?

[image: Swings of derivative where no (red) data point exists]

```
(*universal constants*)
M = 5.9724*10^24; 
R = 6.371*10^6; 
Rs = 8.87*10^-3; 
cLight = 299792458;

(*data*)
year2015 = {{120, 2064}, {240, 2961}, {360, 3765}, {480, 4592}, {600, 
    5122}, {720, 6129}, {840, 6861}, {960, 7789}, {1080, 9019}, {1200,
     9838}, {1440, 10650}, {1560, 12355}, {1680, 13291}, {1800, 
    14812}, {2040, 15724}, {2280, 14821}, {2400, 18093}, {2760, 
    14857}, {2880, 14379}, {3000, 21095}, {3360, 12277}, {3480, 
    26257}, {3600, 27908}, {3720, 28644}, {3840, 29435}, {3960, 
    30091}, {4080, 30720}, {4200, 31284}, {4320, 31783}, {4440, 
    32138}, {4680, 32375}, {4800, 23132}, {4920, 16747}, {5040, 
    12342}, {5160, 8904}, {5280, 6280}, {5400, 4073}, {5520, 1935}};

(*interpolation function and its derivative*)
intF = Interpolation[year2015];
intFder[t_] := intF'[t];

(*function containing interpolation function and its derivative to be \
numerically integrated*)
dtauHtau0[t_] := 1/2 ((Rs  intF[t])/R^2 - (1/cLight intFder[t])^2);

(*the numerical integral*)
tau = NIntegrate[dtauHtau0[t], {t, First[year2015[[1]]], Last[year2015[[1]]]}]
```

Comment: Is the example code related to the ODE? `Plot[dtauHtau0[t], {t, First[year2015[[1]]], Last[year2015[[1]]]}]` makes the result seem reasonable to me. Maybe you can do the integral in `NDSolve` simultaneously with solving the ODE.

Comment: From the help if "Interpolation":  "Interpolation works by fitting polynomial curves between successive data points.".  It is well known that fitting data using polynomials suffer from overshoot6ing if the order is too high. Therefore, try reducing the order. Or try using the option "Spline".

Comment: Looking at your data.  I see two possibilities: 1) You have errors in your measurements and you should be trying to fit a curve to the measurements.  2) If there are no errors, then you don't sufficient information to say what happens between about 2500-3500.  Without some additional understanding that would allow you to guess a functional form in this region, I think you should exclude it from your analysis.

Comment: @Goofy: Yes the data is related to the ODE. It is data describing the flight path of a balloon sat carrying a chip scale atomic clock. The ODE attempts to model the gravitational time dilation experienced by the traveling clock WRT a stationary clock in the lab.